# How do I handle an accusation and blame a co-worker stated they received from a client?

Tags: work-environment

Sorry in advance for the long read.

I work for financial advisers.  A few weeks ago I was advised by an adviser to assist a client in a wire transfer. This would have been my first wire transfer transaction.

I was advised by another co-worker that the wire transfer must be completed before 12 noon. If the client calls after that time we are not able to initiate the wire transfer until the following business day.

The client called after the wire transfer cutoff time.  So I explained to the client what I was advised and let the client know we can process that the following business day.  I did not act unprofessional.  I was apologetic to the client and they seemed fine with not being able to make the wire transfer for them that day.  The client even stated that they will call back Monday to follow through with the transfer.

So I emailed my Adviser and explained the conversation that transpired.  The adviser asked if the client seemed ok with this?  I stated that yes, they seemed fine.  I had no reason to feel otherwise.

3 weeks later the client withdraws a large sum of money and proceeds to tell the adviser that the reason they did this was because I was rude to them.  I can guarantee I was not rude, but in this industry this is where their perception affects the assistants.

The adviser brought this complaint to my attention and told me as a result of this client taking their money out that has "taken money out of his pockets".

I was clearly upset.  I apologized as I felt horrible about this.  I have worked for this company 3 years and never have I had a client complain about me until now.

Anyway, I allowed the day to finish out without approaching my direct manager as I needed to pull myself together.  The very next day I approached my manager explained what transpired between the client, the adviser and myself.

I did not receive the support I was expecting.  In fact the blame was turned around on me and I was told that I just need to take this as a learning experience and chalk it up.  I felt no justice.

The part I left out is that the co worker who advised me of the cut off time for this wire transfer is my managers daughter and that cutoff time was incorrect and that the cut-off time is actually **2pm** not 12pm as I was originally informed.

So with that being said I did explain to my manager I was advised of this time and that I emailed the adviser after the phone call.

I have all supporting evidence that I did everything I needed to do.  I felt I was falsely accused and should not have to take full responsibility for this complaint.

I was only doing what I was told and if that was wrong I did email the adviser and he was aware of the conversation and he didn't take any action to call the client to correct the information about the cut-off time.

My question is how can I clear this injustice up?

Clearly I'm being blamed and I don't feel that is accurate.  My manager did not support me because, well it's obvious that issue was created by incorrect information given to me by his daughter and the adviser brings a lot of revenue into the practice.

**What if anything can I do to make them see that I am not completely responsible for the actions of the client?**

Comment: Hi and welcome to Workplace SE! Your question was very hard to read as a single giant paragraph so I've edited it to break the text up a bit and I've tried to highlight the main question for you. You may want to consider a further edit to cut down on the overall length if possible to make it easier for people to get to the crux of what you're asking.

Answer (score 9):

> What if anything can I do to make them see that I am not completely responsible for the actions of the client?

In this case there probably isn't much you can do - if I'm understanding you correctly you have the "paper" trail to show what you did, why you did it and who you told about it at the time.

Given the particular political circumstances of the other parties involved (daughter of the director and adviser who generates significant revenue) I imagine your manager is reluctant to do anything other than make you the nominal scapegoat. Is it fair? No, not at all. Unfortunately life, and the workplace in particular *aren't* fair and this sort of thing happens the world over. That doesn't make it *right* - just true.

While I can understand that you're feeling hard done by (and justifiably so) from what you've posted it doesn't sound as if your manager has taken any actual disciplinary action against you. Probably because they know that it isn't *really* your fault.

If you are otherwise happy in this job then I'd be tempted to let it go and move on with your life. If this incident is just the tip of the iceberg then I'd probably be looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

You *shouldn't* really do anything at all now. Your manager's response:

> I was told that I just need to take this as a learning experience and chalk it up.

...shows that as far as he's concerned, it's done and dusted. It doesn't sound like you've been formally reprimanded at all, so even though you consider it a major screw up, chances are that they just think it's "one of those things".

By escalating the situation, you only serve to make them think that you're unable to admit to your mistakes, which isn't a picture you want to paint of yourself.

Instead, do what your manager says and take it as a learning experience.

- If you're not 100% sure of the details, check with your adviser / manager directly rather than another colleague;
- Err on the side of caution when reporting that clients are definitely ok with something that inconveniences them - even if they seem fine, saying something like "Well they didn't seem to mind too much, but obviously they didn't sound overly pleased about it" means that you've given a heads up if the situation does turn sour.